# Is there a GUI alternative to Putty SSH for transferring files?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, putty, scp

Or any GUI SSH for Amazon ec2 Linux instance servers?

I need to transfer files between two Linux virtual servers and currently I have PuTTY (which Amazon recommends). However I am new to the server/virtual world and have no experience with commands. I was looking for a GUI for beginners like me so I can basically copy/paste or drag/drop folders into the server.

Is there a friendly GUI out there for this? I was googling a bit and I found SuperPutty? Apparently It has the capabilities but is not fully developed?.

What would you recommend?

Comment: Seriously - if you're going to venture into linux sysadmin, do yourself a favor and learn the CLI.

Comment: Totally agree with @ErikA , take the hit and the small amount of pain.  Especially if you are transferring a lot of data between the virtual servers.  Using a GUI tool, you will more than likely have to copy all the data down to your local machine, then push it all back up to Amazon's cloud.  It will be far quicker to do an **scp** or **sftp** directly between the two virtual servers.

Comment: then learn CLI I shall.

Comment: This question should best be answered by the person in charge of the server's security, because that is as much a policy issue as a technical one. If the person in charge cannot answer it, then by all means get someone on board who can.

Comment: This question made me laugh, as PuTTY *is* already a GUI program, less powerful and more hand-holdy than a normal command-line SSH client. Normally on Windows I'll use Cygwin.

Comment: why would anyone in their right mind want a GUI shell client

Comment: Despite being primarily a Windows admin I can't imagine ever wanting a GUI on a Linux server. I did try it once and still have the emotional scars.

Comment: CLI is hellllll

Comment: Hi, I have learned the CLI. I still want to use GUI though, much easier/faster/nicer.

Comment: MobaXterm nicely combines CLI and UI for the so inclined :-)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I would recommend [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) (I've been using it to transfer files to my virtual private server for years).

Comment: I do have an option for a windows manager.

Comment: @javasocute - I updated my answer as I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to be exactly what im looking for

Comment: I've been using this program for years to transfer files to my Linux server. It had hiccups in the early versions, but now it is really, really stable. Another improvement in the latest versions is that when you move or copy files/dirs from one remote location to another remote location there's no transfer hit. It knows that the file operation is exclusively remote and <I gather> it generates the cp or mv command behind the scenes. I really love this utility. It's saved me thousands of keystrokes. Also, check out the filename copy menu option. I get that and paste it whenever needed in PuTTY.

Comment: Concur, really nice client. It is an added bonus that it is really easy to use in scripts as well as the gui.

Comment: Even though I often use CLI for stuff like this, this is one of the few GUI front ends that meets all my criteria: lightweight, intuitive, stable, extremely useful, and fast.  I've been using it for about 2 years.  About a year ago it occurred to me that maybe I could donate to the developer.  Went over the WinSCP site, yep, Paypal it is.  Developer actually wrote a nice "thank you" email, which of course I didn't expect.  Highly recommended.

Comment: This is fantastic man.

Answer (score 52):

The [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) client is also helpful.  It provides a regular FTP-like interface, but also supports SFTP; if you specify port 22 in the quick-connect box it automatically attempts SFTP, otherwise you can create a connection profile and tell it to use the SFTP protocol.

Comment: + most people already use it when it comes to FTP, so they probably know how to use it

Comment: Also, FileZilal can interoperate with Putty's Agent for handling SSH ID_RSA / ID_DSA keys.

Answer (score 7):

WinSCP is good for transferring files in a familiar way, but unless you intend to learn the command line for most other things, you will quickly hit a brick wall where you cannot complete a given task. It's *not*, as you requested, a GUI alternative to puTTY (which, by the way, *is* a GUI app).

While I love *nix, it's not for everyone. Have you considered using Windows Server instances on ec2 and having your remote desktop available? It seems like it's something you would be more comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

SecureCrt is good (but not free).
http://www.vandyke.com/products/securecrt/

Comment: its got loads of nice features like duplicate a session into another tab, and integration with the sftp client. When you can't get a proper OS, then secureCRT is kind of the next best thing

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for, but there is also [(Bitvise) Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier).

Answer (score 0):

Pac manager is an other GUI for Linux that allows you to manage your ssh connections.

https://sites.google.com/site/davidtv/
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pacmanager/

PAC is a Perl/GTK Gnome replacement for SecureCRT/Putty/etc... It provides a GUI to configure SSH/Telnet connections: users, passwords, EXPECT regular expressions, macros, etc. You like 'SSHMenu'? If so, you must check this tool. Just let me know how do you feel about it!

- Unique Linux application to impletement almost every SecureCRT's functionality.
- Remote and local macros.
- Remotely send commands with EXPECT regexp.
- Cluster connections!! Connections on same cluster share keystrokes!!
- Proxy support.
- KeePassX support!
- Serial/tty connection via cu/tip/remote-tty connections!!
- RDP (via rdesktop) and VNC (via vncviewer) support!!
- Pre/post connections local executions.
- Line-send dealy capabilities.
- TABS OR WINDOWS for connections!!
- Quick access to configured connections via tray menu icon.
- Wake-On-LAN features!
- Many many more I just forgot, and many many more to come (ASA I find time!)
- FREE (GNU GPLv3)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Poderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/), it is a good SSH Client with GUI for Windows.

Comment: last updated in 2006?!

Comment: Yes, i know but it is not a bad program ...

Comment: Link is dead. The new version of poderosa is not free anymore: http://www.poderosa-terminal.com

Comment: last updated news programs?